# Edit text with indentations

Tags: applescript, automator

When editing text in selection using Applescript in an Automator service, is it possible to keep the original indentation whilst adding tabbed spaces in front of it?

#### Automator Workflow and Script

[image: screenshot of automator workflow]

```
on run {input, parameters}
   if "/*" is in item 1 of input then
      set input to replace("/*", "", input as string)
      set input to replace("*/", "", input as string)
      set input to extract(2, 2, input)
      set input to indent(input, false)
      return input
   else
      set input to indent(input, true)
      set input to "/*" & return & (input as string) & return & "*/"
      return input as text
   end if
end run

on replace(searchString, editString, inputString)
   set previousDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to searchString
   set stringItems to text items of inputString
   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to editString
   set outputString to stringItems as string
   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to previousDelimiters
   return outputString
end replace

on indent(input, incrementing)
   set spacing to tab
   set input to input's text items
   if not incrementing then
      set previousDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
      set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
      set output to replace(spacing, "", input as string)
      set AppleScript's text item delimiters to previousDelimiters
      return output
   else
      set previousDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
      set output to item 1 of input as text
      set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed & spacing
      set output to spacing & (every paragraph of output) as string
      set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
      return output
   end if
end indent

on extract(startOffset, endOffset, input)
   set firstParagraph to (first paragraph of input)
   set lastParagraph to (last paragraph of input)
   set firstLine to length of firstParagraph
   set lastLine to length of lastParagraph
   set input to text (firstLine + startOffset) thru -(lastLine + endOffset) of input
   return input
end extract
```

The following snippet demonstrates expected results and current output using the aforementioned workflow and script:

*Sample Input*

```
let c1 = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
let c2 = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
```

*Expected Result*

```
/*
    let c1 = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
    let c2 = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
*/
```

*Current Output*

```
/*
 let c1 = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
 let c2 = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
 */
```

Comment: @wshaheer, can you paste a link to a screenshot of your *Automator* workflow ?

Comment: You need to add examples of input an expected output for the code you've presented and articulate what is and isn't working for you and where. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and even though it points to the SO site, the concept is still applicable here. I'm not going to waste time on a issue that isn't fully articulated and showing examples of input and expected output.

Comment: @user3439894, as per your suggestion I have updated the post. Let me know if you require further clarification

Comment: The `run` _handler_ has an  `if` _statement_ with an `else` _branch_, so you need to show input samples and expected output samples for both _branches_, not just the `else` _branch_.

Comment: @user3439894, the `if` _statement_ checks to see if the text is already formatted, and if so then reverts it back to the original state, i.e uncommented

Comment: So are you saying the `if` _branch_ already works without issue?

Comment: @user3439894, Yes

Comment: I submit to you that the `if` _branch_ does not work properly either. In other words while it does remove `/*` and `*/` it also removes all tab indentation and while that's fine for your Sample Input, it's not if the Actual Input is a nested code block as is then left justifies every line removing all nesting and tabs, not just tabs added when converting to a commented nested block of code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the updated info in your question and the comments. I chose not to use multiple handlers and just process the selected _code_ based on which _branch_ of the `if` _statement_ it fell under. This was tested on selected text in several applications having editable text including Xcode and works as coded.

Comment: Let me know if the, now updated again, answer works for you.

Comment: @user3439894, sorry I’m just having to take care of a few things at the moment. I’ll let you know once I do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Updated to reflect updated question along with comments to achieve the goal of toggling comments in Xcode.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, used in an **Automator** *Service* was tested in **macOS Sierra** and **Xcode 8.3.3** and works to comment the selected *code* or uncomment the selected *code*, within the manner of coding in the *example* **AppleScript** *code*.

In other words, if the selected *code* looks like:

```
void myDelay(float value) {
    NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:value];
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
}
```

And the **Automator** *Service* is run on the selected *code* above, it will look like:

```
/*
    void myDelay(float value) {
        NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:value];
        [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
    }
*/
```

Or if the selected *code* looks like:

```
/*
    void myDelay(float value) {
        NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:value];
        [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
    }
*/
```

And the **Automator** *Service* is run on the selected *code* above, it will look like:

```
void myDelay(float value) {
    NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:value];
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
}
```

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code* for use in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *Service*.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set selectedText to item 1 of input as text
    set outputText to {}
    if selectedText contains "/*" then
        repeat with i from 2 to ((count paragraphs of selectedText) - 1)
            if (count characters of paragraph i of selectedText as text) is 1 then
                copy "" to end of outputText
            else
                copy (characters 2 thru -1 of paragraph i of selectedText as text) to end of outputText
            end if
        end repeat
    else
        copy "/*" to end of outputText
        repeat with i from 1 to (count paragraphs of selectedText)
            copy tab & paragraph i of selectedText to end of outputText
        end repeat
        copy "*/" to end of outputText
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {linefeed}
    set outputText to outputText as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
    return outputText
end run
```

---

**Notes:**

**Xcode** (8.8.3 anyway) does not support nested block commented *code*, meaning that if you comment some *code* with this script and then select additional *code* that includes *code* previously commented by this script, it will throw an error when running the service. You can work around this by changing:

```
if selectedText contains "/*" then
```

To:

```
if first paragraph of selectedText contains "/*" then
```

However **Xcode** will then show the nested commented *code* as having errors. So the real value of this script is to use it only on *code* that will not then be selected again as a larger block after the original commenting by this script.

When uncommenting *code* you should always be sure to select so the first and last lines of selection contain the block comment characters, `/*` and `*/`, with no leading or trailing blank lines in the selection.

Also, **Xcode** has a built-in keyboard shortcut to comment selected lines with a leading `//` by selecting the *code* and pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>. Pressing the same keyboard shortcut removes the leading `//`. This is some ways negates the need to use this scripted solution.

There are third-party plugins for comments in **Xcode** and a **Google** search should be fruitful.

One example is: [BlockComment for Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blockcomment-for-xcode/id1246672247?mt=12)

---

See edit history for original answer before the OP was updated with actual details of the objective.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: When editing text in general, the proposed solution works as expected. However, when I tried indenting text in Xcode, it does not seem to have any effect

Comment: @wshaheer, I just tested this in Xcode and it worked without issue.

Comment: I've tried with just your suggestion alone, however, the result is the same. Just out of curiosity, does indentation settings of Xcode effect this in any way?

Comment: @wshaheer All I can say is I'm using the Xcode Preferences default Indentation settings, have never changed them, and the example AppleScript code has worked for me in every app I normally use where the text is editable. I just noticed you updated your question, adding code and a screenshot. I'll take a look at it in a bit.